# Under the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I'm new to HTML and CSS and trying to create a popup under the button from this tutorial - [How TO - Popup][1].
I tried to change the position, display, and other attributes but that didn't work.

CSS

```
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
    .popup .popuptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 160px;
        height: 160px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 8px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 125%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -80px;
    }

    .popup .popuptext::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    .popup .show {
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
        animation: fadeIn 1s;
    }
```

HTML

```
<button class="popup" onclick="popupShow()"> Calendar
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</button>
```

JavaScript

```
const popupShow = () => {
    const popup = document.querySelector("#myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: `z-index: 1;` try to change the value to `10000` and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have current works correctly but if you only render the button and popup without any additional styles you will find that the absolute positioned popup shows off screen ( because it's positioned absolute ) I've added some body styles to show the popup in the centre of the screen.

I also mis-interpreted your question and thought that you wanted the popup shown at the bottom so it looks slightly different to your example but the principle is still the same.

```js
const popupShow = () => {
    const popup = document.querySelector("#myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
    .popup .popuptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 160px;
        height: 160px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 8px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top:calc(100% + 8px);
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -80px;
    }

    .popup .popuptext::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: transparent transparent #555   transparent ;
    }

    .popup .show {
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
        animation: fadeIn 1s;
    }
```

```html
<button class="popup" onclick="popupShow()"> Calendar
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go instead of using `bottom:125%` use `pixel` values

Also don't forget about the tooltip `position` and its `border-width`

**EDIT**: adjusted the height of the popup for good view

```js
const popupShow = () => {
        const popup = document.querySelector("#myPopup");
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

```css
.popup {
        position: relative;
        display: inline;
        left:50%;
        margin-top:35px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
        .popup .popuptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 160px;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            display:inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 8px 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            /*bottom: 125%;*/
            left: 0px;
            /*margin-left: -80px;*/
            bottom: -85px;
        }
    
        .popup .popuptext::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: -5px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
            border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #555 transparent;
        }
    
        .popup .show {
            visibility: visible;
            -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
            animation: fadeIn 1s;
        }
```

```html
<button class="popup" onclick="popupShow()"> Calendar
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your CSS a little bit. See line with **/*changed*/**.

```js
const popupShow = () => {
  const popup = document.querySelector("#myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 50px; /*add*/
}

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  height: auto; /*changed*/
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -40px; /*changed*/
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -32%; /*changed*/
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent; /*changed*/
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<button class="popup" onclick="popupShow()"> Calendar
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
 </button>
```